# How to remove last space text clipboard applescript?

Tags: applescript

It was:

"hello
hello
hello
"

need

"hello hello hello"

If last characters space to remove
Thank all!

```
get the clipboard
set the clipboard to (replacement of "1" by "2" for the result)

on replacement of oldDelim by newDelim for sourceString
    set oldTIDs to text item delimiters of AppleScript
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to oldDelim
    set strtoks to text items of sourceString
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to newDelim
    set joinedString to strtoks as string
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to oldTIDs
    joinedString
end replacement
```

Comment: @alexander.polomodov, I believe your edit changes what was originally asked, being _how to remove the trailing space from_ "hello hello hello ", **not** how to get `hello hello hello` from "hello\nhello\nhello"!

Answer (score 2):

```
set the clipboard to "hello hello hello "
set theString to get the clipboard
set theWords to text from first word to last word of theString
set the clipboard to quote & theWords & quote
```

RETURNS:

"hello hello hello" -- with quotes

---

If you do not want quotes

```
set the clipboard to "hello hello hello "
set theString to get the clipboard
set theWords to text from first word to last word of theString
set the clipboard to theWords
```

RETURNS:

hello hello hello -- without quotes

Comment: Since I did get the idea after reading your answer, it's only fair I +1 you too. :)

Comment: While the edit you've made obviously works and allows for more then the three words in the OP's example, nonetheless IMO you've added an unnecessary line of code. I see no need to have to first get the count of words, and all that had to change was `set theWords to text from word 1 to word 3 of theString` to `set theWords to text from first word to last word of theString`. With that, no counting of words is required to be coded and the latter does the same thing without the added coding.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the clipboard only contains a single line of *text* as in your question e.g. "hello hello hello ", without the quotes, the following one liner removes the trailing space.

```
set the clipboard to text from first word to last word of (the clipboard as text)
```

Note: This also removes any amount leading and trailing whitespace and is unlimited in the number of words of text the single line of text on the clipboard contains.

Comment: Damn... And I thought my answer was brilliant  LOL  +1

Answer (score -1):

Here's a concise method that compares the last character to a list of white space. Cleaner than a series of if or's.

```
-- set clipboard to "hello hello hello       "
set theString to the clipboard
repeat 99 times
    set c to last character of theString
    if c is in {tab, space, return} then
        set theString to text 1 thru -2 of theString
    else
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
return theString
```

(it's technically faster to grab "text -2 thru -1 of theString" instead of "last character", however that will ignore trailing return characters so won't work for you)